# JSGrid. DeleteRows assertion fail

Tags: sp.js

When I try use this js function:
`jsGrid.DeleteRecords(recordMas, null);`

I catch this message: Assertion Failed: Break into debugger?
[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: Thx for answer! I have jsgrid with hierachy. When I try to remove record from grid, i catch Assertion Failed. If i disable hierarchy - everything is working. What code do u need?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple.

When the window pops out, press pause in debugger. When debugging a unit test using Visual Studio, Debug.Assert failure does not pop up a window, it's like the test framework has removed this feature. (I'm using VS 2013 Pro.)

**Try if you are using in web part:**

Make sure to edit the page and then edit the web part.

- Edit current view for the item and Select all the fields that are required and were not showing in the view.
- Save the view.
- Go back and refresh the page.
- The error should be gone.

Hope this post helps someone out there.